# Where can i get an online version of original works of Aristotlean physics (for free)?

Tags: history, specific-reference, nature

I am trying to search for original works of Aristotle in physics. Pls refer an online version and kindle version is very much appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a physics question.

Comment: Any suggestions for the right place to ask this questions?

Comment: I meant on stack

Comment: Try the History of Science and Mathematics stack.

Comment: Aristotle is more [philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) than physics, since his "physics" pretty blatantly disagrees with reality. Aside from that, we aren't really in the business of locating files upon request (that's for your friendly neighborhood librarian).

Comment: It's one Google search away: http://classics.mit.edu/Aristotle/physics.2.ii.html. -1 for insufficient effort.

Comment: The Wikipedia page has not one but several links including several with the original Greek: was it really so hard to look there?

Comment: All Aristotle's works are available [here from eBooks@Adelaide](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/a/aristotle/). Cf. also [St. Thomas Aquinas](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/)'s [Commentaries on Aristotle](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/) (e.g., his [_In libros Physicorum_](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/Physics.htm)), which includes verbatim Aristotle in both Greek and English and St. Thomas in both Latin and English.

Comment: @ChrisWhite His astronomy more "blatantly disagrees with reality" than his (philosophical) physics.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a listing of the extant works of Aristotle here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_Aristotelicum

There are a couple of sets of translations available at www.archive.org

In answering most of these questions, Google is your friend.